# How can I access a specific character in an <int,string> map?

Tags: c++, string, hashmap, character

I have a map in C++ and I want to access only a specific character in the string. I have a loop that looks something like this.

```
map<int, std::string> line; 

for (int j = position; j < position+WIDTH; j++)
{
    // get the next number
    int number = convertToInt(line[j][position]); // <---Need only 1 char
    std::cout << "Number :: " << number << std::endl;
}

position++;
```

Comment: `line[j]` should give you a string, and therefore `line[j][position]` should be one character of that string? ([And it does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f40f7394b2b64a3c))

Comment: Looks like you have it right.  If the code is not working please include a [mcve] and explain how it does not work and any compilers you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine because

```
line[j]   //retrun string
[position]   //retrun a specific character in place of position of the line[j]
```